# How to check when reading a directory that it is not ".." or "."?

Tags: c

I'm making a program to walk through a directory and all of its subdirectories. And in order not to go to the parent directory, I need to skip the "." and ".."

I tried:

```
char *name = dir_struct -> d_name;
if (name == "." || name == "..") {
     continue
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp`, not `==`. You're comparing the addresses of the strings, not their value.

Comment: Use `fts.h` or `ftw.h` if available on your target platform.